# Inspection of Structs in Swift during debug doesn't work

Tags: xcode, swift, struct, xcode7, lldb

Debugging running a unit test in Swift 2.1 / Xcode 7, this struct is defined -

```
struct MyStruct {
    let x: Int
}
```

Later on, it's printed through -

```
let s = MyStruct(x: 2)
NSLog("s = \(s)")
```

and log shows -

```
2015-11-30 13:45:11.869 myapp[11555:521452] s = MyStruct(x: 2)
```

But writing command `po s` in LLDB results with the following error -

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7f9e93c91df0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

and the struct does not appear in local variables inspector, or it appears but XCode crashes when trying to expand it.

**Turning `struct` into `class` causes this to work well.**

So question is, why does this happen and how to debug structs in Swift?

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce your problem, it [works for me](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOxHNvzhsyJPuoogL27X8YINHe-bYepHQJs) in a sample project (Xcode 7.1.1).

Comment: Printing structs works in the general case, so there must be something specific about your code that is foiling it.  Probably best to work this through a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com, since we'll need to look in more detail to figure out what is up.

Comment: Ran into the same problem when debugging from breakpoint.  Structs having TWO or more properties will not print from lldb debug line if you initialize the Struct into a 'let' constant.  When you 'print myStruct.property' you get a random incorrect value.  If you print the value from within code using print(myStruct.property1) it shows the correct value. Also, initializing the struct into a var will correctly print, however you end up with Xcode warning about immutable var should be a let.

Answer (score 2):

This Solution/workaround works in Xcode 7+:

Declare the constant struct on one line, then assign it to a new Struct on a second line.

```
let structConstant: MyStruct
structConstant = MyStruct()
```

RunTime value inspection will now work on structConstant.  Set a breakpoint anywhere after the assignment (line 2) and the struct values will correctly show in the variables inspector.

The debug console command "(lldb) po structConstant" will also work.